# using array offsets to calculate delta in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I need to create delta and growth rate with a lot of data points. I'm new to numpy but I see it can do internal operations like this.

```
(Pdb) data = np.array([11,22,33,44,10,3])
(Pdb) data + data
array([22, 44, 66, 88, 20,  6])
```

Is it possible to add data offsets in numpy array operations?  Like this delta calculation.

```
(Pdb) [data[i] - data[i-2] for i in range(2,len(data))]
[22, 22, -23, -41]

(Pdb) [data[i] - data[i-1] for i in range(1,len(data))]
[11, 11, 11, -34, -7]
```

Comment: `data[:-2] - data[2:]`?

Comment: @QuangHoang `data[2:] - data[:-2]` but yes i see now how that works. Thanks!